# How to adjust and remove panel axis labels in a multi-panel faceted ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, axis-labels

I've set up a multi-panel / faceted heatmap for covariance matrices using ggplot2. Each panel has the same x- and y-axis labels, however, I would like the labels to only be present on the left-most panels, and along either the top or bottom edge of the panels. I do not want to have x- and y-axis labels for the entire plot though. It currently looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QatQW.jpg)

And I want it to look like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cR0hl.png)

The covariance dataframe in long format:
https://github.com/AnelD13/MSc-Soil/blob/main/YieldCovHav_dfAll.csv

My latest attemt at the ggplot2 code - the problem seems to be within the theme(axis.text) layers, which should be italicised below.

```
(YieldCovHavHeat <- ggplot(YieldCovHav_dfAll, aes(x=Var1, y=variable, fill=Covariance)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors=brewer.pal(9, "Purples"), limits=c(-1, 1)) +
  facet_wrap(~ treatment, nrow=5, ncol=3, scales="free") +
  theme(strip.text=element_text(size=20, face="bold"),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.title=element_blank(), # Remove the axis title
        panel.spacing=unit(0, "lines")) + # Remove the space between panels
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, vjust=1, hjust=1),
          axis.text.y = element_text(angle=45, vjust=1, hjust=1)) +
    *theme(axis.text.x = ifelse(seq_along(unique(YieldCovHav_dfAll$Var1)) == 1, 
                               element_text(angle=45, vjust=1, hjust=1),
                               element_blank())) +
    theme(axis.text.y = ifelse(rep(seq_along(unique(YieldCovHav_dfAll$variable)), each = length(unique(YieldCovHav_dfAll$variable))) == 1,
                               element_text(angle=45, vjust=1, hjust=1),
                               element_blank())) +*
  labs(x="", y=""))
```

I've tried using an if_else statement from dplyr instead of the base package ifelse.

```
theme(axis.text.x = if_else(seq_len(length(unique(YieldCovHav_dfAll$Var1))) == length(unique(YieldCovHav_dfAll$Var1)), list(element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1)), element_blank()))+
theme(axis.text.y = if_else(rep(seq_along(unique(YieldCovHav_dfAll$variable)), each = length(unique(YieldCovHav_dfAll$variable))) == 1, list(element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1)), element_blank()))+
```

Another option was to use geom_text:

```
geom_text(data = data.frame(x = "Var1", y = unique(YieldCovHav_dfAll$variable), 
                              label = unique(YieldCovHav_dfAll$variable)), 
            aes(x = x, y = y, label = label), hjust = 1.2, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
geom_text(data = data.frame(x = unique(YieldCovHav_dfAll$Var1), y = "variable", 
                              label = unique(YieldCovHav_dfAll$Var1)),
            aes(x = x, y = y, label = label), vjust = -0.2, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
```

I can't get any of the code to work. Is there perhaps a simpler version to try?

Edit:
I couldn't make facet_grid work, as I wanted the individual labels to all my treatments. But the solution in facet_wrap is as follows (... = same as in code above):

```
> (YieldCovHavHeat <- ggplot(YieldCovHav_dfAll, aes(x=Var1, y=variable, fill=Covariance)) + 
... 
facet_wrap(~ treatment, nrow=5, ncol=3, scales="fixed") + 
theme(... 
axis.line=element_blank(), 
axis.text.x.bottom=element_text(size=15, angle=45),
axis.text.y.left=element_text(size=15)) +
labs(x="", y=""))
```

Comment: Is there a way to reconfigure this to work with `facet_grid` instead? I think the default labeling there is more like you want.

Comment: Thanks. Looking in to that now :-)

Answer (score 0):

https://teunbrand.github.io/ggh4x/articles/Facets.html

`ggh4x::facet_wrap2()` might be the simplest way to do this.

---

I couldn't access your data so here's an example. I would suggest using `facet_grid`, where you specify the rows and columns, instead of `facet_wrap`.

```
library(dplyr)
storms %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=day, y=lat, fill=pressure)) +
    geom_tile() +
    facet_wrap(~ year, scales="free") +
    labs(x="", y="")
```

[image]

```
storms %>%
  mutate(row = (year - min(year)) %/% 6,
         col = (year - min(year)) %% 6) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=day, y=lat)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill=pressure)) +
  geom_text(data = . %>% distinct(year, row, col),
            hjust = 0, vjust = 1,
            x = -Inf, y = Inf, aes(label = year)) +
  facet_grid(row~col) +
  labs(x="", y="")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. i've added in the line and so far I'm getting weird results but I'll play around with it.